# Maximum length of Azure Resource IDs?

Tags: azure

Is there an absolute maximum length of Azure Resource IDs, independent of the resource type?

Some parts of the structure are fixed (like subscription id) and others like group and resource name have documented limits. But RP namespace and resource types seem to add some unknown into the mix.

```
/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/{resource-provider-namespace}/{resource-type}/{resource-name}
```

Comment: i dont think you will find an answer for this, remember there can be endless subresources

Comment: Good point about the child resources. But still, I was wondering whether maybe there is a limit that is document somewhere because of some underlying storage limitation. So let's see if anybody comes up with something

Comment: The resource IDs are part of a URL so there could be a limit on the URL length at some point?

Comment: If you are trying to store `resourceid` you can guesstimate the max char and every time before insert you may log the length checks. @juunas Although these look like part of URLs they are not. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192808/azure-resource-identifier-format-uri-url-or-urn).

Answer (score 3):

There is no official documentation which specifies the max character limit for Azure Resource ID.

###### Note: So this is not *the answer*, but an *attempt* to answer.

---

Fully qualified resource IDs for the resources have format as mentioned in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.storage.models.resource.id?view=azure-dotnet):

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/{resourceType}/{resourceName}
```

Also, [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules?source=docs) specifies the max allowed limits:

- `subscriptionId`: 36
- `resourceGroupName`: 90
- longest entry for `resourceProviderNamespace` as per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-services-resource-providers) is: 45, but may be assume it to be 64 chars.
- `resourceType`: These can't be guessed. Although there is [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#azure-powershell) to list the types. And  Assume it to be about 256 chars.
- `resourceName`: 512 chars after a quick look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules?source=docs#microsoftcustomerinsights).

| fields | Approx. chars |
| --- | --- |
| `subscriptionId` | 36 |
| `resourceGroupName` | 90 |
| `resourceProviderNamespace` | 64 |
| `resourceType` | 256 |
| `resourceName` | 512 |
| fixed chars | 44 |
| **Total** | 1002 |

**Warning**: This is an educated guess. You're welcome to improve or quote the official figure, if available in future.

Comment: its incredible how difficult it is to find this information from azure docs lol

Comment: Yeah, but again, its not possible to understand, in future, what kind of nested sub-resources can be created. Hence trial & error with something like 4096 chars?