# C#, Is there a better way to verify URL formatting than IsWellFormedUriString?

Tags: c#, url, uri, notsupportedexception

**Is there a better/more accurate/stricter method/way to find out if a URL is properly formatted?**

Using:

```
bool IsGoodUrl = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute);
```

Doesn't catch everything. If I type `htttp://www.google.com` and run that filter, it passes. Then I get a `NotSupportedException`later when calling `WebRequest.Create`.

This bad url will also make it past the following code (which is the only other filter I could find):

```
Uri nUrl = null;
if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out nUrl))
{
    url = nUrl.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: You've probably caught this by now, but you have an extra 't' in your url. For anyone else who might be trying to copy-paste the solutions, make sure you change it to "http" or "https"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("htttp://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute)` returns true is because it is in a form that could be a valid Uri. URI and URL are not the same.

See: [What's the difference between a URI and a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

In your case, I would check that `new Uri("htttp://www.google.com").Scheme` was equal to `http` or `https`.

Comment: Oh wow.. that's good info. I was just under the "assumption" that it was a different name for the same thing (dumb me..).

Comment: @PiZzL3 - I wasn't aware of the difference myself until I researched it (to write my answer to the question I linked to). See my edit above for testing the value of `Scheme`.

Comment: @PiZzL3 - I don't know what other gotchas there might be. Invalid servers come to mind, but you probably won't know if a server is valid or not until you try to access it.

Answer (score 8):

Technically, `htttp://www.google.com` is a properly formatted URL, according the [URL specification](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt). The `NotSupportedException` was thrown because `htttp` isn't a registered scheme. If it was a poorly-formatted URL, you would have gotten a `UriFormatException`. If you just care about HTTP(S) URLs, then just check the scheme as well.

Comment: I figured it was. I just want it to filter according to what can be used, not to spec.

Answer (score 4):

@Greg's solution is correct. However you can steel using URI and validate all protocols (scheme) that you want as valid.

```
public static bool Url(string p_strValue)
{
    if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(p_strValue, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    {
        Uri l_strUri = new Uri(p_strValue);
        return (l_strUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || l_strUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This Code works fine for me to check a `Textbox` have valid URL format

```
if((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TXBProductionURL.Text)) && (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(TXBProductionURL.Text, UriKind.Absolute)))
{
     // assign as valid URL                
     isValidProductionURL = true; 

}
```