# How to assign a urn(uniform resource name) to a url

Tags: url, uri, urn

How to assign a URI/URN to a corresponding URL. What are the steps to do it.
Say i have a URL https://staging.test.com how to assign a URN to it to make it something like
urn:testing:test:stage

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How to assign a URI/URN to a corresponding URL.

Just to clarify: an URL *is* an URI already. See: [What is the difference between a URI, a URL and a URN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

---

> Say i have a URL `https://staging.test.com` how to assign a URN to it to make it something like `urn:testing:test:stage`

You can find a list of registered URN namespaces at http://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces/urn-namespaces.xml. If your ressource isn't "part" of any of these entities, you must not use their namespace. Example: If your ressoure isn't a book with an ISBN number, you must not use the `isbn` namespace. You would have to formally register your own URN namespace.

However: You could use any namespace starting with `X-`.

See [RFC 3406: 3.1: **Experimental Namespaces**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3406#section-3.1):

> These are not explicitly registered with IANA.  They take the form:

> ```
> X-<NID>
> ```

> No provision is made for avoiding collision of experimental NIDs; they are intended for use within internal or limited experimental contexts.