# When calling a web service that returns data, is the data that's being returned over HTTP limited to binary data?

Tags: web-services, http, asp.net-web-api, file-type

Meaning, if I have a web service (a WebAPI) that accesses a file share, picks up a file to return back to the client over HTTP (this file is a 50mb `.tpk` mapping file), is the data that the calling client receives limited to binary data (meaning, the client will have to encode the binary data back to the `.tpk` file extension in order to use it)?  Or can the data that's returned to the client retain the `.tpk` file extension so conversion wouldn't be necessary?  Forgive my slight ignorance on this, this is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking is, "can you return content types?" If my interpretation of your question is correct, then the answer is yes.

[This article might be helpful](http://www.infoq.com/articles/subbu-allamaraju-rest)

Or did I completely bork the interpretation?

Comment: If `.tpk` isn't a supported content type, then I would imagine conversion at that point would be necessary, right?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you want the client to do with it. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185490/rest-api-and-delivering-a-binary-resource ?