# How to use this.getClass().getResource(String)?

Tags: java

I cant understand what the error of this code.

```
public void run(String url) {

        try {
            FileInputStream file;
            file = new FileInputStream(this.getClass().getResource(url));
            Player p = new Player(file);
            p.play();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.print( url + e);
        }
    }
```

when i try to run it, it says me "no suitable constructor found for FileInputStream(URL)". Why its happening?

Comment: because there is no FileInputStream constructor which takes a URL as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the file in root of folder of your class path (folder where your `.class` files are generated) and then use statements below:

```
  InputStream inputStream = 
                  getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
  Player p = new Player(inputStream );
```

Here `filePath` is the relative file path w.r.t. the root folder.

Comment: thanks a lot. its working. but you know i cant understand when, how and where we need to use it. Its very complicated for me.

Comment: @Tushar: What is complicated? Let me know, I will try explaining to you.

Comment: I just want to know how the line getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath); works.

Comment: @Tushar: getClass().getClassLoader() finds the class loader of your current class where you have written this code. The classloader is aware of the location from where it loaded your class file. This is file was required to be placed in the same location. getResourceAsStream reads your file from the location and returns the input stream. Let me know, if you need more explanation.

Comment: sure, I will be great full if you provide me more explanation.

Comment: @Tushar: Put your new question. I will try help you understand.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

- `getClass().getResourceAsStream(classpathRelativeFile)` for classpath resources
- `new FileInputStream(pathtoFile)` for file-system resources.

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler to use getResourceAsStream

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);
Player p = new Player(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of FileInputStream constructor is File, String ... (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html ), but Class.getResource return URL (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), not File, or String.
Try to use

```
public void run(String url) {

    try {
        FileInputStream file;
        file = new FileInputStream(new File(this.getClass().getResource(url).toURI()));
        Player p = new Player(file);
        p.play();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.print( url + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The method Class.getResource(String) return a URL, while the parameters of constructor of File is String, or URI... (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html). The URL.toURI() method return an URI object which represent the URL.
You can see the different between URI and URL in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier