# Remove duplicate trailing slashes

Tags: php, regex, string, url

I would like to detect with `php` if a string like `$string` include duplicate trailing slashes.

For example:

```
$string = "http://somepage.com/something/some.html/////";
```

to

```
$string = "http://somepage.com/something/some.html";
```

And I wanna do an `if`, if it has duplicate, something like:

```
If ($string = "http://somepage.com/something/some.html/////";) {
    remove extra trailing slashes
} 
//else do nothing...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `rtrim()`:

```
$string = rtrim($string, '/');
```

If you for some reason want to first check if it has trailing slashes then you can check the last character, like so:

```
if ($string[ strlen($string)-1 ] === '/') {
    $string = rtrim($string, '/');
}
```

Throwing the string through `rtrim()` is not expensive so you do not really have to check for trailing slashes first.

Using regular expressions to trim trailing slashes is a little over-kill.

Comment: if ($string[ strlen($string)-1 ] === '/') {
    $string = rtrim($string, '/');
} .. What does $string[ strlen($string)-1 ] means... Why is $string an array? ... I don't understood, but it looks like the best solution for me. I have two types of URL... for example: http://mikrobusz-berles.com
and http://mikrobusz-berles.com/flotta.html ... and I just wanna to remove ebery extra slashes... at .html it is easy, but what's about when i write:
http://mikrobusz-berles.com///////////
?

Comment: You can access characters inside strings using `[]`. `rtrim($string, '/')` removes all forward slashes on the right. See the [documentation](http://php.net/string#language.types.string.substr) before asking more questions.

Answer (score 9):

apply [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) like so

```
$string = rtrim($string, '/');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = rtrim($string, '/');
```

Answer (score 3):

`rtrim` is the best solution but since you tagged `regex` for completeness:

```
$string = "http://somepage.com/something/some.html/////";
echo preg_replace('#/+$#','',$string);

>>> http://somepage.com/something/some.html
```

---

```
#   - Is the delimiter character 
/+  - Matches one or more forward slash
$   - Matches the end of the string
#   - Delimiter 
Replace with 
''  - Nothing (empty string)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are places where `/` can be duplicated, for example, you can access your question through all these links:

- [Remove duplicate trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes/)
- [Remove duplicate trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes////)
- https://stackoverflow.com///questions///13990256///remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes////
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions//13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes//

The only double `/` that makes difference here is the `http://`, so let's consider it. `rtrim` alone will not work in most of the cases I provided, so let's go with regular expressions.

### Solution

```
$parts = explode('//', $full_url, 2);
$parts[1] = rtrim(preg_replace('@/+@', '/', $parts[1]), '/');
$full_url = implode('//', $parts);
unset($parts);
```

Live test: http://ideone.com/1qHR9o

```
Before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes/
After:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes
---------------------
Before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes////
After:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes
---------------------
Before: https://stackoverflow.com///questions///13990256///remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes////
After:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes
---------------------
Before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions//13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes//
After:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes
---------------------
```

### Explanation

From your question I understand that you always get a complete URL, so, we can split it in two parts:

```
$parts = explode('//', $full_url, 2);
```

Now we remove the duplicated `/` with:

```
preg_replace('@/+@', '/', $parts[1])
```

Then we remove the extra `/` from the end of the string:

```
$parts[1] = rtrim( /*previous line*/ , '/');
```

And implode it back:

```
$full_url = implode('//', $parts);
unset($parts);
```

Comment: I have no idea, I voted it up for you to compensate :) The explode part is bit tricky though. I would prefer an exclude regex, which simply excludes the `https?://` part. Because, what if there is no protocol defined in the url? Then it will fail.

Comment: @Jelmer actually, if there's no protocol defined, then you don't have an URL, you have an [URI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url) and the data would be invalid, but it can be easily tested by checking if the size of the array is 2, although I test if the parameters are valid when I receive then.

Comment: All the OP wants is to remove **trailing** forward slashes in a string which `rtrim` is the perfect solution for, the question you have answered is validating forward slashes in a `URL`.

Comment: @sudo_O ok, I didn't know trailing means "at right", I always understood it as multiple or in sequence. That was a language barrier.

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior Ahh okay yes `trailing` means `found at the end`

Comment: Ah! Explode/implode. Thank you :) I found out my `sanitizePath()` function *accidentaly* removed double-slashes in `http://`, too, which was an unwanted behaviour. I was looking for a simple and short solution and found this. Excellent :)