# MySQL Regular Expression for Finding internal URL's with a Double Slash in the Body

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

We have a site using wordpress and we have discovered that at some point, a bad plugin or user error has added double slashes after the siteurl (for example, `http://example.site//category1/` or `http://example.site/category1//category2/`, etc.

This seems to work but it looks like there aren't quite enough results.

```
SELECT id, post_content
FROM `wp_posts`
where post_content
regexp '(href="[^"]*[^:]\/\/[^"]*)'
and post_status  in('draft','publish')
order by id asc
```

Is there a better way to do this? I don't want it to match on the double slash that comes after the http:, hence the negative match on the :.

Edit: for clarification, I want to find all posts (the body of a wordpress post/page) that have a url hard-coded into the page that has double slashes, but do not match on the double slashes after the http:.

Regexp should match on the following:
`http://example.site//category1/` or `http://example.site/category1//category2/` or even `http://example.site/category1/category2//` or `example.site/category1//category2/`

But should not match on the following:
`http://example.site/category1/` or `http://example.site/category1/category2/`

Comment: add in another set of slashes: `[^"]*[^:]\/\/.*?\/\/` so it'll look for TWO sets of double slashes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990256/remove-duplicate-trailing-slashes

Comment: what about a simple LIKE: `WHERE post_content  LIKE '%site.com//%'` ?

Comment: @bonCodigo: That doesn't help if the slashes are not on the end of the url.

Comment: There's an answer in that post which talks about even the in between `//`..

Comment: @MikeM: No, they don't always begin with href="

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work.

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE CASE WHEN instr(post_content,'http://') > 0 THEN 
  substring(post_content,7) regexp '\/\/'
ELSE
  post_content regexp '\/\/'
END
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edee2/12).

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for using [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
regexp '(https?:\/\/|www\.)[^ ]*\/\/'
```

This will match a post if it contains `http[s]://` or `www.` followed by non-space characters which have `//` among them.

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84d15/1) (adapted from the fiddle of sgeddes).

Or you could just reduce your regex to `'[^:]\/\/'` and look for posts containing that.