# What is the difference between URI and Uri class

Tags: java, android

I am confused , how to use `Uri` because i am using it in android development at `Intent's` `Action dial`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:555-2368"));
```

What I want to do :

I want to create a file inside which I want to put 2 phone numbers. Then, I want to use `toUri()` method  with this file, and want to put that `Uri` in the intent, then I want to see what happens with the intent.

Comment: What stops you from doing it as you described?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Android API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29) you can create a file `Uri` with:

`public static Uri fromFile (File file)`

Answer (score 6):

`java.net.URI` is mutable

`android.net.Uri` is immutable

[java.net.URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html)

A Uniform Resource Identifier that identifies an abstract or physical resource, as specified by RFC 2396.

[android.net.Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)
      . A URI reference includes a URI and a fragment, the component of the URI following a '#'. Builds and parses URI references which conform to RFC 2396.

In the interest of performance, this class performs little to no validation. Behavior is undefined for invalid input. This class is very forgiving--in the face of invalid input, it will return garbage rather than throw an exception unless otherwise specified.

Comment: please give a simple example ,

Comment: what is the benefit of making them as immutable .

Comment: java.net.URI is not mutable.  From JavaDocs:

"This class provides constructors for creating URI instances from their components or by parsing their string forms, methods for accessing the various components of an instance, and methods for normalizing, resolving, and relativizing URI instances. Instances of this class are immutable."

Answer (score -1):

URIs identify and URLs locate; however, locations are also identifications,
so every URL is also a URI, but there are URIs which are not URLs.

URL - http://example.com/some/page.html

URI - /some/page.html