# Launching a web-link from onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying my hand at developing an app for android, and the java is a bit confusing. The code I have so far is....

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButtonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonClick);

    final String link = "htttp://www.stackoverflow.com";

    ButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            URI uri;
            try {
                uri = new URI("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });}}
```

The issue with the way the code is currently written is when I try to assign the new intent (browserIntent), uri in what I understand to be the "data" part of that object. Android Studio says that uri cannot be converted to a URI, but it's declared as a URI only a couple of lines above!

I also tried to insert a string of text, initialized above as well, which looks like...

```
           browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link);
```

This compiles fine, but when I actually click on the button it says that there is no activity to handle the intent.

So my questions in order are:
1) If I declare the URI uri variable earlier in the code, and the second property of the intent is looking for a URI, why is there an error when I simply feed it the variable uri?
2) In the second case, when I am trying to parse the string, where there is no activity to handle the intent, is this issue with ACTION_VIEW? It seems that its able to find the URI fine, however it can't actually go through with opening a browser. Perhaps 
3) What is the simplest java api or java tutorial that would cover this issue that you have found or know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS must be saying something like "uri is not initialized", because due to try-catch block that isn't guaranteed. So, we change the code as following:

**EDIT:**

Silly me, we need to use the `Uri` class instead of `URI` class as there is no constructor `new Intent(String action, URI uri)` but there is one for `new Intent(String action, Uri uri)`. For differences between `URI` and `Uri`, visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031418/what-is-the-difference-between-uri-and-uri-class).

```
ButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri;
            try { 
                uri = Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
                browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        } 
    });}}
```

Comment: You have put `Button BottonClick;` somewhere, right?

Comment: Yeah it's on the xml page in terms of the layout.

Comment: yesss it works! Thank you very much! For your information I'm trying to build an app where a user can click on a link, and the phone pulls up A)

Comment: yesss it works! Thank you very much! For your information the thought that generated this interest is - I'm working on a list of "merchants" and "products they sell"; my goal is to allow a user to do a search on either merchants or products they sell, and the application outputs information about the business, which includes a link to their website or any digital presence. So I probably need to start focusing on how to use an app, or a java application, to query a database or a spreadsheet. I can keep you informed if you'd like.

Comment: however, after i made those changes, android studio also showed an error message in the try/catch statement because the catch statement that's there would not have been executed. Not an error really, just a FYI.