# java URI with file:// only

Tags: java, file, uri

I wonder if it is possible to create an URI with only file://?
I tried but I get `URISyntaxException`.

So my question is why this work with URL but not with URI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url

Comment: @Baadshah I can't see a straight-forward answer to this question in that link.

Comment: Baadshah sorry, but this link make anything clear
my question is why file:// work with url but not with uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double forward slash `//` has special meaning in the `hierarchical part` in the [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)

Quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax)

> The hierarchical part of the URI is intended to hold identification information hierarchical in nature. If this part begins with a double forward slash ("//"), it is followed by an authority part and a path. If the hierarchical path doesn't begin with ("//") it contains only a path.

The `hierarchical part` in the URI `file://` begins with a double forward slash `//`. In this case an optional `authority part` is expected after witch the `path` follows.

The statement

```
URI uri = new URI("file://");
```

results in

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 7: file://
```

since the string passed is [violating](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String%29) the [specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) for an URI.

The statement

```
URL url = new URL("file://");
```

will throw no Exception but will fail with a `FileNotFoundException` wenn trying to open the input stream since no path was specified.

If you don't want to specifiy an `authority part` then this musst be done with respect to the specification, witch means either you leave it empty and specify the path right after the `//`

```
URI uri = new URI("file:///");
```

or just dont put a `//` in your URI string and start directly with the path

```
URI uri = new URI("file:/");
```

Both are equivalent an will result in the same URL. Opening the input stream and reading it will just print a listing of your root directory.

Comment: A4L Thnak you!!!! I understand now my mistake.