# Use URI to store image URL or image path

Tags: android, uri

I have a class that have a reference to an image. This image can be on a server or among the drawable resources of the app. I need to store the location of either the url or the drawable location of the image file.
In order to handle this, I'm using an Uri as attribute of the class.

First of all, is this a right solution?
Then, how can I check if the Uri has a reference to the drawable or a reference to an URL?
And how can I store the location of the drawable resource in the Uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose is *one* solution. It's hard to say if this is the *right* solution without seeing some code.

I haven't tried this myself but apparently you're able to use an Uri to a drawable like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/image_name");
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

This means that you should be able to store the URI as a String in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). The next time you need to load the image you retrieve the URI string from SharedPreferences and if if the string starts with "android.resource://" you load the image using the content resolver and [BitmapFactory.loadStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29). If the string doesn't start with "android.resource://" you get an input stream to the image on the web using whatever Http framework you decide to us (OkHttp, UrlConnection, Android Async Http etc).

Comment: Ok thank you! I'm gonna try it. One more question please... what is the difference between URI and Uri? I've read the documentation, but I didn't get it...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1984225/1266551 In my example the Uri identifies a specific resource, but it says nothing of it's location. It is up to the content resolver to actually find the location of the content in the Uri and provide an input stream to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("string");
```

in this string you can pass the url or the name or path of the image.