# Why do I get 'System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.' when using an IPv6 URI?

Tags: c#, ftp, uri, ipv6

Why does this `var uri = new Uri("ftp://1111:2222:3333::43/testing/1kb.zip");`

Throw this exception?

> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: Invalid port specified. at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [RFC 2732](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt):

> To use a literal IPv6 address in a URL, the literal address should be
>      enclosed in "[" and "]" characters.

For example, this works fine:

```
var uri = new Uri("ftp://[1111:2222:3333::43]/testing/1kb.zip");
```

If you want to specify the port, it needs to be outside the square brackets:

```
var uri = new Uri("ftp://[1111:2222:3333::43]:100/testing/1kb.zip");
```

Comment: Jon, i read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1984225/22656 and am confused why following is wrong new Uri("Prerak/Kaushik/SomeResource"); Thanks.

Comment: @PrerakK: This sounds like it should be a new question. In particular, it has *nothing* to do with this question about IPv6 representations. (But in brief: you haven't specified a URI scheme name in there.)