# To create URL - what's the difference between using uri.parse / uri.builder / concatenate string?

Tags: java, android, uri

I read from the documentation about how uri can provide more efficient way of creating url but I am confused as of what's the difference between the following 1, 2 and 3 method?

1)Build url using Uri.Builder. Example:

```
Uri.Builder.scheme("https")
            .authority("abc.example.com")
            .appendPath("search")
            .appendQueryParameter("id", "123")
            .appendQueryParameter("name", "dummyText")
            .build();
```

2) using Uri.parse. Example:

```
Uri.parse("https://abc.example.com/")
            .buildUpon()
            .path("search")
            .appendQueryParameter("id", "123")
            .appendQueryParameter("name", "dummyText")
            .build();
```

3) concatenating Strings with similar parameters above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st & 2nd are quite similar. `Uri.Builder` is nested static class of`Uri`. Also `Uri.buildUpon` method returns `Uri.Builder` instance. The only difference is that the former one is more structured and developer-friendly as you don't need to care about `:` & `/`. For your third query, you should look at this post [uri string difference stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017459/uri-url-and-string-what-is-the-difference).