# xdocument.load (url) or (stream)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am confused about xdocument.load.

I did a search and found [MSDN XDOCUMENT.LOAD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It does not state that you can supply a URL as a load option, but you can and it does work by the many examples I found.

So, is this documented anywhere? Is it better to use WebResponse to get a stream?

I am confused, please help.

Comment: It mentions "A URI string that references the file to load into a new XDocument" as a description for the parameter.

Comment: Yes, is that only referring to a file? Does it also include a HTTP string?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url - Uri's can be Url's

Answer (score 1):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e96wzcy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The XmlUrlResolver class is the default resolver for all classes in
>   the System.Xml namespace. It supports the file:// and http://
>   protocols and requests from the WebRequest class. In many cases, if
>   you do not specify an XmlResolver object that your application should
>   use, an XmlUrlResolver object with no user credentials is used to
>   access XML resources.

So behind the simple APIs taking a string with a URI an XmlUrlResolver is used.