# What is an URI in android

Tags: android

I have recently come across an android object that makes no sense to me. I can't understand what a URI is.

I checked the [Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) and it said:

> Immutable URI reference. A URI reference includes a URI and a
> fragment, the component of the URI following a '#'. Builds and parses
> URI references which conform to RFC 2396.

The problem is, you can't use a URI to explain what a URI is! I am totally confused.

I did some research and came across [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928844/what-is-uri-in-android). But it said

> Uri does nothing

Could someone please explain to me what this means?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier

Comment: URI is like a URL on the internet (Uniform Resource Locator) but wider in scope. eg `file:///something.txt`, `http://www.example.com/`, `ftp://example.com`. Each different string before the `:` indicates a different protocol/handler. In Android, URIs are used to point at other apps, actions, etc eg `tel:+44123456789`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2498596/156755) for an example using a Uri to make a phone call

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a URI, a URL and a URN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn)

Comment: [This](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html) RFC Document might help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. Q: What is a "URI"?

   A: The technical meaning of "URI" is defined in [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a compact sequence of
>   characters that identifies an abstract or physical resource.

2. Q: What is an Android "URI" class?

   A: Here is the Javadoc for [android.net.Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)
3. Q: But what do we *need* the Android "URI" class for?

   A: Look at the "Content Providers" section of the Android documentation:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
>
> Content providers manage access to a structured set of data. They
>   encapsulate the data, and provide mechanisms for defining data
>   security. Content providers are the standard interface that connects
>   data in one process with code running in another process.

For example...

> `public final ContentProviderClient acquireContentProviderClient (Uri uri)`
>
> Returns a ContentProviderClient that is associated with the
>   ContentProvider that services the content at uri, starting the
>   provider if necessary.

If you're curious, here's what Tim Berners-Lee had to say about URIs (he's the guy who invented them ;)):

> http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Axioms.html#uri
>
> Universal Resource Identifiers
>
> The Web is a universal information space. It is a space in the sense
>   that things in it have an address. The "addresses", "names", or as we
>   call them here identifiers, are the subject of this article.  They are
>   called Universal Resource Identifiers (URIs).
>
> An information object is "on the web" if it has a URI.  Objects which
>   have URIs are sometimes known as "First Class Objects" (FCOs).  The
>   Web works best when any information object of value and identity is a
>   first class object.  If something does not have a URI, you can't refer
>   to it, and the power of the Web is the less for that.
>
> By Universal I mean that the web is declared to be able to contain in
>   principle every bit of information accessible by networks. It was
>   designed to be able to include existing information systems such as
>   FTP, and to be able simply in the future to be extendable to include
>   any new information system.
>
> The URI schemes identify things various different types of information
>   object, wich play different roles in the protocols. Some identify
>   services, connection end points, and so on, but a fundamental
>   underlying architectural notion is of information objects - otherwise
>   known as generic documents. These can be represented by strings of
>   bits. An information object conveys something - it may be art, poetry,
>   sensor values or mathematical equations.

Comment: One question I failed to answer: Q: What is an Android "URI Reference"?  Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html), in the "Class Overview" section of Uri.Builder.  This also answers the question about "URI" vs. "URI fragment".

Answer (score 5):

URI(Uniform resource identifier) as its name suggests is used to identify resource(whether it be a page of text, a video or sound clip, a still or animated image, or a program).

The most common form of URI is the Web page address, which is a particular form or subset of URI called a Uniform Resource Locator (URL).

Android uses URI string as the basis for requesting data in a content provider (i.e. to retrieve a list of contacts) and for requesting actions (i.e. opening a webpage in a browser)

Answer (score 1):

I am adding details from RFC that center around the abbreviation URI and some examples in use:

From,
http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html

> This document updates and merges "Uniform Resource Locators"
>   [RFC1738] and "Relative Uniform Resource Locators" [RFC1808] in order 
>   to define a single, generic syntax for all URI.

And,

> 1.1 Overview of URI
>
> URI are characterized by the following definitions:
>
> ```
>   Uniform
>      Uniformity provides several benefits: it allows different types
>      of resource identifiers to be used in the same context, even
>      when the mechanisms used to access those resources may differ;
>      it allows uniform semantic interpretation of common syntactic
>      conventions across different types of resource identifiers; it
>      allows introduction of new types of resource identifiers
>      without interfering with the way that existing identifiers are
>      used; and, it allows the identifiers to be reused in many
>      different contexts, thus permitting new applications or
>      protocols to leverage a pre-existing, large, and widely-used
>      set of resource identifiers.
>
>   Resource
>      A resource can be anything that has identity.  Familiar
>      examples include an electronic document, an image, a service
>      (e.g., "today's weather report for Los Angeles"), and a
>      collection of other resources.  Not all resources are network
>      "retrievable"; e.g., human beings, corporations, and bound
>      books in a library can also be considered resources.
>
>      The resource is the conceptual mapping to an entity or set of
>      entities, not necessarily the entity which corresponds to that
>      mapping at any particular instance in time.  Thus, a resource
>      can remain constant even when its content---the entities to
>      which it currently corresponds---changes over time, provided
>      that the conceptual mapping is not changed in the process.
>
>   Identifier
>      An identifier is an object that can act as a reference to
>      something that has identity.  In the case of URI, the object is
>      a sequence of characters with a restricted syntax.
> ```

Here are some in use:

> 1.3. Example URI
>
> The following examples illustrate URI that are in common use.
>
> ftp://ftp.is.co.za/rfc/rfc1808.txt
>         -- ftp scheme for File Transfer Protocol services
>
> gopher://spinaltap.micro.umn.edu/00/Weather/California/Los%20Angeles
>         -- gopher scheme for Gopher and Gopher+ Protocol services
>
> http://www.math.uio.no/faq/compression-faq/part1.html
>         -- http scheme for Hypertext Transfer Protocol services
>
> mailto:mduerst@ifi.unizh.ch
>         -- mailto scheme for electronic mail addresses
>
> news:comp.infosystems.www.servers.unix
>         -- news scheme for USENET news groups and articles
>
> telnet://melvyl.ucop.edu/
>         -- telnet scheme for interactive services via the TELNET Protocol