# Cannot find protocol 'resource' in URL constructor

Tags: java, url, junit, protocols

I've implemented a class to read from RSS 2.0 and Atom 1.0 feeds. I want to write some unit tests in order to verify functionality. Here is the feed reader section of my code:

```
private String readFeed(final String url) throws IOException
{
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    final URL feedUrl = new URL(url);
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(feedUrl.openStream()));

    String input;
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        builder.append(input);
    }
    in.close();

    return builder.toString();
}
```

After some research, I figured the best way to test would be to have a sample feed as an XML file in my project resources directory.

I've created a example file "resources/rss2-0.xml"

I'm sending in the following value to the readFeed function, "resource:///rss2-0.xml",
and I keep receiving java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: resource

This is my first time using a URL pathway to load from a resource. From what I can tell, resource seems like it should be a valid protocol. Anyone have any ideas what I may be doing wrong or other ways to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deal with path using your local file system, the [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class is best suited for this task.

> An object that may be used to locate a file in a file system. It will
>   typically represent a system dependent file path.

You can use it like so :

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/resources/rss2-0.xml");
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

If your really want to deal with URL, the protocol you're looking for is simply "file". So it would be `file:///rss2-0.xml` instead of `resource:///rss2-0.xml` and even `file:/resources/rss2-0.xml` to be exact.

Note that in your case, you will indeed have to deal with [URLs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) sooner or later, but when working on local tests, using the Path class will save you troubles. If you want another alternative, try the [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class. Since an URI is an *identifier* (see [difference between URI and URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)) it can identify either an URL or a Path an may serve as a bridge between your production code which will ultimately deal with URLs and your test code where the Path class could be best put in use.

For example :

```
public interface FeedReader {
    String readFeed(final URI uri);
}
```

And 2 implementations, one for testing locally :

```
public class LocalFeedReader implements FeedReader {

    @Override
    public String readFeed(final URI uri) {
        // URI -> Path
        // then dealing with Path to target local rss2-0.xml file
    }
}
```

And one for production code :

```
public class WebFeedReader implements FeedReader {

        @Override
        public String readFeed(final URI uri) {
            // URI -> URL
            // then dealing with URL to target real resources
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The java docs say that only http, https, file, and jar are "guaranteed" to exist on the search path for protocol handlers. Others only "may" be supported.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-java.lang.String-

It looks like if you want a custom handler that isn't supported in your java distribution, you'll have to create one.

http://mjremijan.blogspot.com/2012/02/create-your-own-java-url-handlers.html