# URI is the same like relative URL?

Tags: url, uri

I am making own URL generator and there is a problem. I have absolute URL and I need to get relative URL from it.

Relative URL is path and query, like URI, so is this the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a URI and a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you please explain it better? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the relative url depends on the context.

absolute is: c:/home/user/test.zip

relative (when context is c:/home) to test.zip is: ./user/test.zip (or user/test.zip)

Comment: You did not answer my question. I asked, if URI is the same like relative URL.

Comment: URI is not relative URL. (Edit: i am wondering if it is not easier to just look at wikipedia)