# media(String str) allow no space in the str

Tags: java, media, space

```
private static final String MEDIA_URL =     
    "file:///d:/dt_32bars_120tribal.wav";
    //"file:///d:/Linkin Park - Numb.mp3"; 
 Media media = new Media(MEDIA_URL);
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

When I use the `file:///d:/dt_32bars_120tribal.wav`; the program can work. But when I use the second one: `file:///d:/Linkin Park - Numb.mp3`; it cannot work.

After I rename the MP3 as `LinkinPark-Numb.mp3`(remove all space), then I use `file:///d:/LinkinPark-Numb.mp3`; it can work now.

Does this mean that the `Media()` cannot allow space in the file name? but as we all know that sometimes the name of mp3 files contain several space. How can I deal with it?

Comment: try file://d:/dt_32bars_120tribal.wav but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [File.toURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI()) to generate a properly escaped URI string:

```
new java.io.File("abc def.mp3").toURI().toString();
;; => "file:/.../abc%20def.mp3"
```

See the [Media(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media(java.lang.String)) documentation:

```
The supplied URI must conform to RFC-2396 as required by java.net.URI.
```

Spaces, e.g., have to be escaped as `%20`.

Comment: [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) - just a way to represent "special" characters (like whitespace) in certain contexts, most prominently URIs/URLs.

Comment: thank you! one more question, what is the difference between URI and URL. I suppose that i know what is URL

Comment: I don't think I can come up with an explanation as good as [this other SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1984225/1916789), so there you go. :)

Comment: xsc, thank you very much. although i am not quite clear of all the concepts mentioned there, at least i have some idea of that.