# Valid url check form validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

Here is code I have for a url validation function in CI, and this is the callback function

```
function valid_url($facebook)
    {
        $pattern = "/^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([w]{2}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?/";
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $facebook))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
```

I'm getting this error

```
Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '|'
```

Comment: Check out [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) for URL implementation. Check out [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) for URI implementation. Check out [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) for examples. Check out [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url) about difference between `URL` and `URI`. Make sure of percent encoded strings are properly matched too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        function validate_url($url) {
        $data = trim($url);
        $data = stripslashes($url);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($url);
        return $url;


     // check address syntax is valid or not(this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
        if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$url)) {
        return FALSE;
        } else {
    return TRUE;
    }
     } 
  $check =  validate_url($url);
```