# HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL - Incorrectly named function?

Tags: javascript, url, uri, data-uri

It is, under my current understanding, incorrect to declare that a data URI is, in fact, a URL.

So, with that under consideration, would I be correct in saying that the JavaScript function [`HTMLCanvasElement.getDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) has been named incorrectly? Or is there a specific reason for why it was named the way it was.

I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28865728/2529423), since it states that a data URI is *not* a URL.

Comment: The answer is in the question you link to. Why do you ask again?

Comment: The reason I asked is because I was amazed that a silly mistake like the difference between URL and URI got through the spec approval process in the first place, and I wanted to know if there was a specific reason for why it might be named in that way. I shall, reword the question, as it is not entirely clear as to what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WHATWG has decided that it is desirable to

> Standardize on the term URL. URI and IRI are just confusing. In practice a single algorithm is used for both so keeping them distinct is not helping anyone. URL also easily wins the search result popularity contest.

https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#goals

Web browsers now have a built-in, standardized `URL` object which is used to create Blob UR**L**s. Say goodbye to the URI.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the general agenda is to phase distinctions between URL types out?

Comment: Look @thephpdev , if you want a discussion about that, StackOverflow is not the right place. Use the WHATWG mailing list or the spec project on github.

Answer (score 2):

It might be considered inaccurate by contemporary definitions of URI and URL, but according to the [W3 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsRFC2397) the naming is based on [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397), which defines the data **URL** scheme.

Comment: I see now, thank you. It seems as though concrete/consistent definitions of URL/URI are nonexistent.

Comment: That RFC is from 1998. However, the "incorrect" use of URL in the sense of URI has been preserved in the far more modern [URL spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#local-scheme).

Comment: @Touffy Thanks for the link. I specifically mentioned 2397 as it is referenced in the spec that defines the behavior of the method in question.

Comment: Yeah actually I re-read the URL spec and found a better answer there, straight from the mouth of the WG (see my post)