# Image View error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an application for Android devices and I need 10 pictures in a row with the same padding and text between them.

I tried to do that with padding but when I run the gallery section the app closes (Name has stopped.).

In my Logcat I get this error:

```
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class <unknown> 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj.GalleryFragment.onCreateView(GalleryFragment.java:19) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 23 more 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:817) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:126) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:116) 
01-21 16:10:34.813: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 26 more
```

Comment: Could you post the xml code?

Comment: **Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**. Looks like your image takes a lot of memory than allotted for the app. You need to scale the image down.

Comment: use uri instead of bitmap

Comment: But, I don't know how(beginner).Do you mean "url".

Comment: @HaxhiBekaj read the docs @ http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Do you mean url instead of bitmap?

Comment: are you using ImageView to display images?

Comment: @HaxhiBekaj: [Difference between URL, URI, URN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn)

Comment: Yes I'am using ImageViews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main cause to this issue is Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

You can resize your bitmap file using BitmapFactory which you can find in this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)

Comment: Thanks a lot , this helped me a lot .I don't know how to reward you.♥

Comment: @HaxhiBekaj no problem glad i could help.