# BitmapFactory.decodeFile() returns null value for a camera picture

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have an android app where I go to the camera activity and take a photo, and then I execute the following code:

```
        String s1 = file_uri.getPath();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( s1, options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50,  stream);
```

where the file_uri is the image path from the phone storage (it is not null) bitmap variable is null. Why?

Comment: You are using the uri.getPath() as the actual path to your file. Instead, you should [get the real path from Uri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore).

Comment: I will check it now. What is the difference between them?

Comment: I honestly don't know the difference. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn/1984225#1984225) might clarify things a little bit, but I still get confused about them.

Answer (score 0):

your image may be too big and you get out of memory

Comment: what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

```
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( s1, options);
```

After those statements `bitmap` is always `null`'. That's normal.

```
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( s1, options);
```

Now you can have a bitmap. If not then the bitmap would be to big for available memory and `decodeFile()` had returned null;

Then you should resize your image.
In variable `options` you can find the width and heigth of the image. 
With knowing pixels width and height you could calculate a scale factor. Or just say `int scale = 8`;`.

```
   options.inSampleSize = scale;
```

After that do another call like

```
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( s1, options);
```

Presise code for this has been posted many times on stackoverflow.

Comment: the bitmap is still null

Comment: Then show the adapted cods in a new code block in your original post.