# Database URI or URL?

Tags: sql, url, uri

So I read this [What is the difference between a URI, a URL and a URN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn) but I'm still not sure whether it's a database URL or URI.

For example MySQL could have something like this:

```
mysql+mysqldb://scott:tiger@localhost/test?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0
```

Is this an URL or URI?

Comment: @davejal I hope you're not serious? I did read, why else would I ask? -.-

Comment: This pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGWwt.png say all URL are URI and same for this https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKFwk.png but this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeX0x.png disgaree,

Answer (score 7):

I think the link in the comments is good enough but I can see there is a need for a **TLDR;**.

Here is my take on it:

- A URI is the generic version -- it includes everything as optional.
- A URL not only includes the location it also include how to work on that location (eg http:// for the protocol).
- A URN is just the name that should be unique, it can look like a URI or URL but the semantics (being unique) are what define it.  (eg https://stackoverflow.com/users/215752/hogan)

This is the quick version --- there might be minor inaccuracies and side cases but maybe this gets you going in the right direction?

Hat tip: If it still exists feel free to look at the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier). I believe it is clearer than the answer mentioned in the comments.

*The answer to your question is that it is both a URL and a URI*