# Confusion between dataURI and dataURL in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between data URI and data URL?

Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). Both of these terms are used, but how are they different?

By the way, this is different from the posts mentioned to be possible duplicates. It's not a HTTP question ! This is javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a URI, a URL and a URN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn)

Comment: https://danielmiessler.com/study/url-uri/

Comment: No. This question is not the same as that one. My question is regarding the difference between these two terms in javascript language.

Comment: It doesnot matter. URL,URI and URN's mean the same in any language.
Take a look at the 1st comment and : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: why the method name is URL ? and it returns dataURI ? why aren't both URI or both URL ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh javascript doesn't have different definitions of URI and URL (and URN), they are named and built based on the HTTP definitions

Comment: In my opinion, this is a fair question. The documentation is confusing, and the potential duplicate doesn't address the specific concern of @ArianHosseinzadeh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

URIs are a superset of URLs. All URLs are URIs, but some URIs are not URLs. [This answer has the proper definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn). As you can surmise by reading them, there's a gray area that depends on context.

As for your specific question, `getDataUrl()` returns an URI. It is not a URL, since it doesn't really include any information regarding how to locate the resource externally. **The function is not named appropriately**, as the [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) reflects.

**But**, this information is implicit: as the data blob lives inside the URI itself, there's only one place where it can be found. **So you could argue, as you sip from your tea and adjust your monocle**, that it *is* a URL, since no further clarification about protocol, schema or location is needed.

In other words, this is highly subject to interpretation. I wouldn't pay much mind to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion arises from this

> The HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() method returns a data URI containing a representation of the image in the format specified by the type parameter (defaults to PNG). The returned image is in a resolution of 96 dpi.

Noting the usage of both `toDataURL` and the documentation calling the value a data URI. What it comes down to is that the method name for the canvas element to get a data **URI** is called **toDataURL**.

Since the URL must specify the location of the data, or in other words, the means by which it is accessed, (think http:// https:// etc) it probably doesn't fit the return value of `HTMLCanvas.toDataURL()` and so the documentation correctly calls the returned values a data URI. Why they decided to name the method `toDataURL` I couldn't say, except that the differences between the two are nuanced, and they may have felt it was easier to remember if they called it `toDataURL`