# Is a (local) file path a URI?

Tags: url, path, uri

On some input we allow the following paths:

- C:\Folder
- \\server\Folder
- http://example.com/...

Can I mark them all as "URI"s?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`C:/Folder` and `/server/Folder/` are file paths.

`http://example.com/` is a URL, which is a URI sub-type, so you could mark it as a URI but not the other way around (like how squares are rectangles but not vice versa).

Of course, here you have posted a clear, simple example. When discussing the distinction between URI and URL, not only is the answer not clear cut, it is also disputed. I recommend taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn) thread and the answers posted in it for clarification. Generally though, it is mostly agreed that the main difference is that URLs provide an access method (such as http://).

So if we were to convert your first file path into a URL it would become the following (note the addition of the access method):

```
file:///c:/Folder/test.txt
```

If you modify all your file paths to include an access method like in my example, then it will be okay for you to mark them as URIs.

Comment: Thanks so far! In your thread reference someone writes 'A file path is not a URL or URI unless you put the file:// prefix on it.'

Comment: Darn. Told you the answer wasn't clear cut. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking no, unless you make sure it's an absolute path and add add "`file://`" to the beginning.

As per [RFC 3986 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3):

> ```
> URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
> hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
>             / path-absolute
>             / path-rootless
>             / path-empty
> ```

The `scheme` and the `":"` are not in square brackets `[]`, which means they are not optional.

However, the HTML standard calls these ["path-relative-scheme-less-URL strings"](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#path-relative-scheme-less-url-string) and they're valid in the `href` attribute of an HTML element so maybe it's fine to call relative Unix paths "URLs" (not absolute Unix paths or Windows paths though).