# Android: How to use the onFragmentInteractionListener interface provided by a Fragment by default

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i its probably a basic question, but i cant figure it out with google.

When i create a new Fragment in Android Studio, it provides an interface named "onFragmentInteractionListener" which has to be implemented by the Activity that contains this Fragment.
The Fragment also provides an "onButtonPressed" method that calls the onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) method in the Interface.

But i have no idea how to use it. How to get a Button Click Event from the Fragment to the Activity? 
I let the ButtonView call the onButtonPressed method. But how does it continue from there?
And what does URI mean here? I googled it, but i dont understand it in the context of this problem.

Comment: Unclear  why a URI is needed, but here's that question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn

Comment: I saw that other question, but no answer there explains how to use it. Just how and why to implement it (what i already did)

Comment: It's an interface, so there's no other way to use it than implement and call it

Comment: I have that same interface in every fragment and 1 time in the activity. I also have more than 1 button in every fragment. How do i get the button click to the Activity? I dont understand it, thats why i asked this question.

Comment: The URI parameter can be changed to whatever data needs to be sent back to the Activity, and you can define multiple interfaces. The default name can be overriden too. Reading over the full example here should clarify why you'd use it, but it's not required. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: You only need one interface defined  if all Fragments send the same data to the Activity

Comment: Ok thank you, ill try to understand it tomorow with the link you sent me. Its already past 2am here.

Comment: Welcome, and good luck. Regarding the question here, the 'onFragmentInteraction(uri)` method of the interface does go to the Activity (or any class that implemented that interface), but that's setup in onAttach to the Activity. It's the recommended way to get data to the Activity rather than calling `getActivity()` followed by a method call