# Is there a proper name for URL schema followed by colon and double slash?

Tags: url, terminology, url-scheme

Is there a word for the URL schema/protocol taken together with the colon and two slashes, for example `http://`, `mailto://`, `ftp://`?

I thought to call it a prefix, yet Microsoft already has UrlPrefix. Probably copyrighted.

Comment: It's the scheme. This information is available from e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Definition

Comment: according to wikipedia schema is just schema, e.g. http, emailto,

Comment: Yes, is that not what you're asking? What's the point of this?

Comment: Nope, the question is about http://, mailto://, ftp://

Comment: I am correcting verbiage on a web page

Comment: As you can see from the diagram `:` and `//` are delimiters, they don't have names AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738) – Uniform Resource Locators (URL) – is surprisingly silent on that matter.

However, in the URI [RFC3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986), we find:

> e.g., most registered names beginning with "www"
> are likely to have a **URI prefix of "http://"**

Via: [RFC3986 Section 4.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-4.5) -- Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax

Note that URIs are a superset of URLs and that for a URI, only a schema and path (which may be empty) is required.

See: [Syntax Components](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3)

More on the difference between URL and URI:

- https://danielmiessler.com/study/difference-between-uri-url/
- [What is the difference between a URI, a URL and a URN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/176264/89391)

Answer (score 0):

For all A and B such that A://B, A is defined as the schema of B