# How to get smtp uri

Tags: javascript, smtp, amazon-ses, firebase-extensions

I have an application that I am working on and I want to use Amazon ses smtp to send email.
I am using firebase as a backend. Firebase has a Triggger Email extension that I want to use. I have managed to do everything right but the Trigger Email extensions asks for smtp URI. I am getting smtp URL from amazon ses. How do I get a smtp URI instead of URL.

Edit - So URL and URI are same. So I should change my question.

Trigger email wants a URI in this format - smtps://username:password@smtp.hostname.com

I am getting this from amazon aws -
email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

So now my question is how to use amazon aws ses smtp with firebase trigger extension.

Comment: A URL is a URI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn

Comment: I should have written the format sorry. I'll fix it now.

Comment: please know that I didn’t say URLs and URIs are the same. — It looks like you already have the URL you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should be your URL:
`smtps://username:password@email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`

Ensure the whole string is URL encoded.

Comment: And username is your smtp username and password is your smtp password. Don't use your amazon aws password or IAM username and password. And ass @tyrion saaid, encode your smtp password. Use this -

`
let result = encodeURIComponent(<YOUR PASSWORD HERE IN STRING>);

console.log(result) `