How to open a generated html file in a new window on flutter web
I am using url_launcher package and trying to open a link like this:
try {
    final Uri launchUri = Uri.dataFromString(
        '<html><body>hello world</body></html>',
        mimeType: 'text/html');
    await launchUrl(launchUri);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

Only a blank screen with empty head and body tags open.
There is no error in the console.
How do I open an html file hard coded on flutter on a new window on flutter web?
should i create a blob?

WebView seems to require a URL.  A URI is not always a URL.  More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn

One possibility is, save the generated html to the local file system. Then open that local file (with a file url) in the new window.

How do I do this?

Flutter file create/write/read - https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Try This Package : flutter_html
Example :
Widget html = Html(
  data: """<div>
        <h1>Demo Page</h1>
        <p>This is a fantastic product that you should buy!</p>
        <h3>Features</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>It actually works</li>
          <li>It exists</li>
          <li>It doesn't cost much!</li>
        </ul>
        <!--You can pretty much put any html in here!-->
      </div>""",
);


Looks like the simplest solution. :-)

yupp :) , it does work also :)
