# S3 Bucket website only works with /index tail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to reach my S3 website at thetoddlertown.com and I reach and XML error page. However, if I visit thetoddlertown.com/index, I reach the home page. I'm not sure why this is happening. I also have the index document set to index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on **Static website hosting** in the properties page.

It will give you a slightly different URL that will automatically redirect to default `index` and `error` pages. The normal bucket URL will *not* redirect.

Comment: I just figured out what the solution is, thank you for the input though but I had already done this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not set the default root object in my cloudfront distribution. After setting it to index.html, my site worked as expected.

Comment: This does indeed fix the problem of default routing to an error but it isn't enough to get a SPA working for instance as both the error page and the index pages need to be working as per the static website hosting configuration. If you have static website hosting configured correctly as I had, the problem is that you are probably routing incorrectly. Refer to this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377823/2180290